# Compare between rows in standard sql

Tags: sql

I wish to compare rows in this fashion and retain only condition satisfying rows

Compare row1 with row 2

- if id and product for both rows are different then retain both rows
- if id and product for both rows are same and difference between Rate  >60 then retain both rows
- if id and product for both rows are same and difference between Rate<60 then remove lowest Rate row

The data is:

```
Id  Product   Rate
1    101         500
2    101        1000
2    101        1010
2    102        1100
3    103        1150
3    103        1250
```

The output is:

```
Id  Product   Rate
1    101         500
2    101        1010
2    102        1100
3    103        1150
3    103        1250
```

The solution given for row comparison are mostly for 2 fixed rows. here it is any number of rows so not sure if self join will work here.

The data is sorted by id,product and Rate. So i need to check 1st row with 2nd, then 2nd with 3rd and so forth.

**Possible Soln: In MySql we can define a variable and use the same in a select query which can calculate for each row. Is it possible to leverage something like that to identify rows which can be removed and then use another query to remove those flagged?**

Comment: You description mentions two rows.  Yet, your data has five rows.  Please fix the explanation.

Comment: Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** "sorted". There is no such thing as "row 1" and "row 2" *unless* you have some criteria on which to apply an `order by`. I don't see any obvious column that could be used to specify the sort order so that "row 1" and "row 2" would make sense. And please add the expected output based on your sample data to the question.

Comment: The way to find duplicates is usually to `group by` on what is identical for a grouping to happen. Various flavours of SQL then usually have additional tools to help facilitate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a complex query for the same. The logic is to compare row1 and row2 in each group and store to another subset, Compare subset with row3 of the main set and create subset2, compare subset2 with row4 in main set and create subset3 and so on.. The logic is based on SQL Server

```
--- Use a common table expression to sort and give a rownumber

with ctex(ID,product,rate,level)as (
select ID,product,rate,
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Id,product order by id,product) as level 
from ds),

-- Use the cte to create another cte with the result of comparison of row1 and row2 of each group

seccteX(ID,product,rate,level) as(

select a.* from ctex a inner join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and a.level =1 and b.level =2 and abs(a.rate-b.rate )>60
union 
select b.* from ctex a inner join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and a.level =1 and b.level =2 and abs(a.rate-b.rate )>60
union 
select b.* from ctex a inner join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and a.level =1 and b.level =2 and abs(a.rate-b.rate )<60
union 
select a.* from ctex a left join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and a.level =1 and b.level =2 where a.level=1 and b.level is null
)

-- Use both cte to compare the results with level 3(row3) of each group
-- We can create as many subsets(ctes) based on the levels. but upto a defined max level

select a.* from seccteX a inner join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and b.level =3 and abs(a.rate-b.rate )>60
union 
select b.* from seccteX a inner join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and b.level =3 and abs(a.rate-b.rate )>60
union 
select b.* from seccteX a inner join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and b.level =3 and abs(a.rate-b.rate )<60
union 
select a.* from seccteX a left join ctex b on a.ID=b.ID and a.product=b.product
and b.level =3 where b.level is null
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `lag()` function to access the "previous" row?

Answer (score 0):

Below query should do, please bare in mind that this 'properly' works only for no more than two values per same id, product combination.

```
SELECT
    x.id,
    x.product,
    x.rate
FROM
    datTable AS x
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        product,
        min(rate) AS low,
        max(rate) AS high,
        max(rate) - min(rate) AS diff
    FROM
        datTable
    GROUP BY id, product) AS y ON (
        x.id = y.id
        AND x.product = y.product)
WHERE
    y.diff = 0
    OR (
        x.rate = y.low
        AND y.diff > 60)
    OR x.rate = y.high
```

Comment: There is my problem. I cant be sure how many rows for same id,Product combination. it could be more than 2 rows